# Updating node an npm

Tags: node.js, command-line, npm, gulp

I am trying to update my npm.

If I type

> npm -v

I get following error:

> -bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory

If I try using sudo I get:

> sudo: npm: command not found

Comment: What is the result of `$ whereis npm` ?

Comment: @TGrif it results in nothing.. falls back to $

Comment: Is there already an installed version of npm ? And how do you make to install it? By the way, which OS do you use ?

Comment: @TGrif npm -v now returns npm: command not found. I am using a MacBook Pro with El Captian OS

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install *npm* with `npm install -g npm`.